# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in python 2.7 when importing pyqtgraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, coredump, pyqtgraph

So I've been working on a python project in which I wanted to use pyqtgraph to plot data from a sensor in real-time.

However, when first trying to run the code, I got a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

I could isolate the one line of code responsible for the crash which was  `import pyqtgraph as pg`.

Running gdb yielded:

```
gdb python

[...]
Reading symbols from python...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/bin/python 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyqtgraph

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00000000004ee6f6 in PyString_FromFormatV ()
#2  0x0000000000506e80 in PyErr_Format ()
#3  0x00007ffff0e69acb in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#4  0x00007ffff58143a3 in initQtGui () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#5  0x0000000000427992 in _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule ()
#6  0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000004e2dec in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000556cf1 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000569cd8 in ?? ()
#10 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#11 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#12 0x0000000000555551 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#13 0x00000000005b41e2 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#14 0x00000000005b429a in PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx ()
#15 0x00000000005942af in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000556838 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000556d9b in ?? ()
#19 0x0000000000569cd8 in ?? ()
#20 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#21 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#22 0x0000000000555551 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#23 0x00000000005b41e2 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#24 0x00000000005b429a in PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx ()
#25 0x00000000005942af in ?? ()
#26 0x0000000000465804 in ?? ()
#27 0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#28 0x0000000000556838 in ?? ()
#29 0x0000000000556c4b in ?? ()
#30 0x0000000000569c08 in ?? ()
#31 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#32 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#33 0x0000000000567d14 in ?? ()
#34 0x0000000000465a2d in PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags ()
#35 0x0000000000465b49 in PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags ()
#36 0x00000000004661fe in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags ()
#37 0x0000000000466d92 in Py_Main ()
#38 0x00007ffff7814f45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x466e50 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd8c8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffd8b8)
    at libc-start.c:287
#39 0x0000000000577c2e in _start ()
(gdb) 
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00000000004ee6f6 in PyString_FromFormatV ()
#2  0x0000000000506e80 in PyErr_Format ()
#3  0x00007ffff0e69acb in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#4  0x00007ffff58143a3 in initQtGui () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#5  0x0000000000427992 in _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule ()
#6  0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000004e2dec in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000556cf1 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000569cd8 in ?? ()
#10 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#11 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#12 0x0000000000555551 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#13 0x00000000005b41e2 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#14 0x00000000005b429a in PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx ()
#15 0x00000000005942af in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000556838 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000556d9b in ?? ()
#19 0x0000000000569cd8 in ?? ()
#20 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#21 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#22 0x0000000000555551 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#23 0x00000000005b41e2 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#24 0x00000000005b429a in PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx ()
#25 0x00000000005942af in ?? ()
#26 0x0000000000465804 in ?? ()
#27 0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#28 0x0000000000556838 in ?? ()
#29 0x0000000000556c4b in ?? ()
#30 0x0000000000569c08 in ?? ()
#31 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#32 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#33 0x0000000000567d14 in ?? ()
#34 0x0000000000465a2d in PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags ()
#35 0x0000000000465b49 in PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags ()
#36 0x00000000004661fe in PyRun_AnyFileExFlags ()
#37 0x0000000000466d92 in Py_Main ()
#38 0x00007ffff7814f45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x466e50 <main>, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd8c8, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffd8b8)
    at libc-start.c:287
#39 0x0000000000577c2e in _start ()
(gdb) 
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00000000004ee6f6 in PyString_FromFormatV ()
#2  0x0000000000506e80 in PyErr_Format ()
#3  0x00007ffff0e69acb in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sip.so
#4  0x00007ffff58143a3 in initQtGui () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so
#5  0x0000000000427992 in _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule ()
#6  0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000004e2dec in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000556cf1 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000569cd8 in ?? ()
#10 0x00000000004c8c8b in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#11 0x00000000005264a8 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#12 0x0000000000555551 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#13 0x00000000005b41e2 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#14 0x00000000005b429a in PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx ()
#15 0x00000000005942af in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000055642f in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000556838
```

Running the same in Python3 worked totally fine, but using Python3 is not an option for me, since this would conflict with a large part of the frame of my project.

I also tried reinstalling pyqtgraph via pip several times.

```
$ pip show pyqtgraph
Name: pyqtgraph
Version: 0.10.0
Summary: Scientific Graphics and GUI Library for Python
Home-page: http://www.pyqtgraph.org
Author: Luke Campagnola
Author-email: luke.campagnola@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
Requires: numpy
```

I have been searching and trying for hours now and haven't found any solution, so I would appreciate any help.

Cheers

A despaired programmer.

Comment: What is your operating system and your Qt version? How did you obtain `PyQt`?

Comment: My first guess is that it is not related to PyQtGraph but to PyQt4 since the former is a pure python package. What happens if you start the Python 2 command prompt and type `from PyQt4 import QtGui` ?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04
About PyQt I don't know, it was preinstalled when I began to work there.

I also tried import PyQt4 but it didn't change anything and `from PyQt4 import QtGui` did not cause any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Python 2.x and 3.x are link-compatible.

You are loading a 3.x module into 2.x Python, and that is simply not expected to work.

You need to build (or find somewhere) a 2.x version of pyqtgraph.

(I am surprised you don't get warnings to this affect before the crash.)

Comment: Indeed. The `pip` above seems to belong to Python 3. To install PyQtGraph under Python 2 you must find the `pip` of the Python 2 package and use that to install PyQtGraph.

Comment: I did try it on my own notebook with python version 2.7.13 and 3.6.1.

Comment: In 2.7.13 I got the error `no module named pyqtgraph`
In 3.6.1 it worked fine.
On my work notebook however, no error message appeared, just the Segmentation fault.

Comment: @Ramdambo "no module named ..." -- yes, as I said above, you need to either build it yourself, or find a prebuilt copy that was built *for* python 2.x